# Can't sent REST message to Google FCM from ServiceNow

Tags: android, rest, google-cloud-messaging, http-status-code-401, servicenow

I'm trying to send REST messages from `ServiceNow` tool to FCM, but getting `"Invalid username/password combo"` message. Firstly wanted to test this in POSTMAN, but still getting `[JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0.]`. 
The full error message I get from `ServiceNow` is as following:

> DEBUG: origin=push auth="MTdhMzhhNTJmZGMxNGQwMGJjNjY4Mjc5YTEzNDBiMWM6U1d0Y1RjOUE1T2paQWd2NTdmVUg=" Adding authorization header
>   SEVERE *** ERROR *** app="[APP_NAME]" request=b819e5c92ea4b2006ead1a337b41f078 origin=push elapsed=41 status=401 rest error message: Method failed: (/fcm/send) with code: 401 - Invalid username/password combo

As we're not using any login/password for REST message, I assume there must be an issue with Server Key. I've read many threads here about 401 error, but still could not fix an issue. I'm using the long one (not legacy) server key from FCM console cloud messaging tab.

Kindly help, if someone has any ideas

Comment: Are you saying that this is not working from Postman either?

Comment: I was able to figure it out. With postman I can now send the message successfully (just missed to add a proper content to it before).

Then when I'm sending a Push Notification (with REST message) from ServiceNow to my custom Android app, I can't get the message delivered, it stuck in pending status (in ServiceNow push log). In ServiceNow system log I can see 401 error. Still checking it, there may be an issue with an app itself.